# BB Code in comments

Tags: discussion, comments

When pasting a link into a comment I follow the same syntax as a post but I get the markup and the link showing, others don't. Seriously what am I doing wrong?

> [ ... ][#]
>
> [#]: link

What tags are supported here also? (Surely this has been asked before on the main site but I can't find it there either...)

Comment: This is what I mean [FAQ][1] [1]: http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't use BB Code, it uses [Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#links).

Try this:

```
[Google](http://google.com)
```

Comment: Well I wasn't sure what it was called and thats why I couldn't find it thanks for the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#links) That works!